# Oninput event in ace.js

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have a few editors on one page. They are stored in an array.

How to determine the editor where I enter text?

```
    for(var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        editors[types[i]].on('input', function() {
            console.log( ? ); // How to get a current editor?
            //console.log(editors[types[i]]); // Doesn't work
        });
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the examples [Here](http://alloyui.com/examples/ace-editor/real-world/), you can see that ace's `on` functions have a `this` variable that references the caller

```
for(var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
    editors[types[i]].on('input', function() {
        // EG:
        console.log(this);
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not jQuery function. I need to use ace.js event (http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor)